# Laravel search query does not working using elquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have query like below, which fetch the records.

```
$posts = User::whereHas('roles', function($q)use($search){
                    $q->where('name', '=', 'agent')
                    ->where('first_name', 'like', "%".$search."%")
                    ->orWhere('last_name','like',"%".$search."%")
                    ->orWhere('created_at','like',"%".$search."%");
                })->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order,$dir)
            ->get();
```

I the above query I am using for pagination means to get next 10 records, but it does not working.

Following variables are posting from ajax

```
$limit = $request->input('length');
$start = $request->input('start');
$order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
$dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');
```

Ajax is working fine but I always get first 10 records when I submit for next 10 records. Can someone kindly help. Thank you

Comment: You're mixing AND and OR in your subquery. You'll need to add another enclosure to separate out there ORs. You also never pass in an offset.

Comment: @aynber can you please post the answer I would very appreciate. I need help +1

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping See the second `where()` in that example, how it wraps a `where()` and `orWhere()` clause? See if you can implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues: You never pass in the offset, so you'll always get the same 10 records. And you mix your AND/ORs, so that it won't limit the name to agent. So to fix it, pass the ORs in another enclosure:

```
$posts = User::whereHas('roles', function($q)use($search){
    $q->where('name', '=', 'agent')
        ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('first_name', 'like', "%".$search."%")
                ->orWhere('last_name','like',"%".$search."%")
                ->orWhere('created_at','like',"%".$search."%");
        });

})
    ->offset($start)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->orderBy($order,$dir)
    ->get();
```

Comment: When I submit search input with some keyword then it is working fine but when I submit search as blank to get next 10 records then it is always showing first 10 records this is the problem I am facing

Comment: Actually `if(empty($request->input('search.value'))){` is not checking correctly

Comment: If you want to get the next 10 records, you'll need to either save or pass the search in again, or else it's not going to have the search to look for, and you won't be paging off the same results. If the input is not checking correctly, you may want to `dd($request->input());` or `Log::info($request->input());` to make sure you get the right values.

Answer (score 3):

For searching with multiple column with single key you can do like this:

```
$employee = Employee::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', '=', 'developer');
            })
            ->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                if ($search != '') {
                    $query->where('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
                    $query->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
                    $query->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
                }
                $query->Where('type', '2');
            })
            ->offset($start)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy('employee_name')
            ->get();
```